# Recycler view is not scrolling smoothly - Cardview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Hi I am using a recycler view with a card view, I have no idea why it is not scrolling smoothly. it stuck for a few seconds and shows the next content.

This is my xml for list item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/product_list_item_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/product_name_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="name"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/product_catagory_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="catagory"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/product_end_date_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="End Date"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

this is my recyclerViewAdapter

```
    class ProductsRecyclerViewAdapter(private val clickListener: (Product) -> Unit): RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductsMyViewHolder>() {

    private val productsList = ArrayList<Product>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProductsMyViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding: ProductsListItemBinding =
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, R.layout.products_list_item, parent, false)

        return ProductsMyViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return productsList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProductsMyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(productsList[position], clickListener)
    }

    fun setList(products: List<Product>) {
        productsList.clear()
        productsList.addAll(products)
    }
}

class ProductsMyViewHolder(val binding: ProductsListItemBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    fun bind(product: Product, clickListener: (Product) -> Unit) {
        binding.productNameTextView.text = product.name
        binding.productCatagoryTextView.text = product.catagory
        binding.productEndDateTextView.text = convertLongToTime(product.end_date)
        binding.productListItemLayout.setOnClickListener {
            clickListener(product)
        }
    }

    fun convertLongToTime(time: Long): String {
        val date = Date(time)
        val format = SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy")
        return format.format(date)
    }
}
```

This is my fragment where i initialise the ProductsRecyclerViewAdapter

```
 private fun initRecyclerView() {
        binding.productsRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        adapter = ProductsRecyclerViewAdapter ({ selectedItem: Product -> listItemClicked(selectedItem)})
        binding.productsRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
        displayProductssList()
    }

  private fun displayProductssList() {
        productsViewModel.products.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            Log.i("MYTAG", it.toString())
            adapter.setList(it)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })
    }
```

any thoughts what I might be doing wrong here

your suggestion would be very helpful

thanks in advance
R

Comment: Did you test this on an emulator? if yes, restarting the emulator helps because sometimes my emulator lags a bit too.

Comment: I have closed an re opened it still it happens

Comment: @MehranB i just tried this on my phone it runs without any scrolling issue

Comment: why is this happening on emulator?

Comment: Dude I was looking at your code and thinking what the ...! everything looks fine! :)) I guess sometimes the emulator runs out of memory or whatever. I actually have no idea. I'm glad the problem is solved.

Comment: in emulator it still has the same issue may be i will try to clear it and rerun, but glad it is not the code as it is running fine on the phone

Comment: No problemo. Have fun

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see in your code is creating new SimpleDateFormat on every bind, it is definitely not free. Create single instance in adapter.
Also, maybe your products observer executes too often?

Comment: Yeah I can't see anything particularly heavy happening in ``onBindViewHolder``, and even the ``SimpleDateFormat`` shouldn't be a big deal. If it's literally freezing for several seconds that's a sign your app overall is doing too much work, and maybe scrolling is just how you notice it, because it's a constant animation and interaction. It could just be the emulator running badly, but you can always profile your app to see what's taking up all its time: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler